# php explode to get last integer from url

Tags: php

i am trying to get the last integer in the url i am using php explode which gives the last value after / but i dont know how to get the last integer just before the /

my url is

```
    http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/quotesalphalist.php?page=124/ABCD
```

i am interested in getting 124 from the above url.

i can get the last value ABCD with the below explode code but dont know how to get 124

```
    $c=explode("/",$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);  $city=end($c);
```

please suggest how to get 124 like integer from the above url.please note that this 124 ma y change to any number but it will be always number and just before last /

Comment: Isn't it better to get value of $_GET['page'] and explode it then?

Comment: Yeah using $_GET would be better, but one question remains, why would you add /ABC to a get variable just to remove it later ? maybe you can just use multiple variables ?page=124&letters=ABCD ?

Comment: @ThomasLang some kind of weird routing, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$c = explode('=',$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);
$result = explode('/', end($c));
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: thanks works like charm .can u please explain above code little

Comment: he's exploding at the `=` symbol, so you only have left 1234/ABCD in your variable, then he explodes again for the '/' and get the first index. Or he could have done like:  $c = explode('/', $GET['page']); echo $c[0];  same result.

Answer (score 2):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working installation of PHP handy to test this, but **as long as the digits precede the last `/`**, then something like this should work:

```
$string = "http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/quotesalphalist.php?page=124/ABCD"
$matches = array();

if(preg_match("/(\d+)\/[^/]+$/",$string,$matches)){
  echo $matches[1] . "\n";
}
else{
  echo "Not matched!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $digit = explode("/", $_GET['page']);
    echo $digit[0];
    /// or using preg_match
    preg_match("/(\d+)\//", $_GET['page'], $matches);
    echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
// Parse the URL into its components
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Parse the query string into the $out array
parse_str($url['query'], $out);

// Echoes out `124/ABCD`
echo $out['page'];
```

If you want to only get the numeric portion, you can then run a quick [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on the string.

```
// Echoes `124`
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "" , $out['page']);
```

Comment: well, you made it too complicated!

Answer (score 0):

Using $_GET:

```
$page = explode('/',$_GET['page']);
echo $page[0]; // 124


$_GET['page'] = "124/gea2ABC23gaga1D";
echo (int) $_GET['page']; // 124
```

Using Request URI:

```
$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] = 'http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/quotesalphalist.php?page=124/ABCD42141';

if(preg_match("/page=(\d+)/",$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ],$matches)){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

not recommend if the second part of the parameter has numbers:

```
$_GET['page'] = "124/gea2ABC23gaga1D"; // -> 1242231 !
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "" , $_GET['page']);
```